# get current webbrowser url or webbrowser content

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I made a login button and want to check if the user logged in or not. I though 2 ways to do that.

1. Check if the webbrowser url is equal with a url (If user login successfully the url is url1, and if not the url is url2)
2. Check if the current webbrowser content contains a word (for example if user login successfully, then in the redirected page should have "Thank you" message)

I want to mention that all is working my only problem is to check if he logged in or not

```
public void Login()
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", txtUsername.Text);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", txtPassword.Text);
    foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
    {
        if (item.OuterHtml.Contains("input_submit"))
        {
            item.InvokeMember("Click");
            break; // Here the webbrowser redirect right?
        }
    }
    if (webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText.Contains("Thank you"))
        con = true;
    else
        con = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use **HttpRequest**  to emulate the login progress,use **HttpResponse** to get webserver response and content and use global **CookieContainer** to store the cookies.

When you get login successful message,you can use other HttpRequest with globval CookieContainer  to get any web pages you want download or access.

i hope this may help you.

you can use Httpwatch(www.httpwatch.com) to watch how Internet Explorer exchange data with WebServer.you can also use IE9 devloper tools to do this(press F12 in IE9).