# How can I click on a button without an ID

Tags: vb.net, getelementbyid

I'm using VB.Net and i'm using 
`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click")`

But I can't seem to find the actual ID. I'm trying to find the sign in button id from the site: http://grooveshark.com/#!/login

Any solutions?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250669/get-current-webbrowser-url-or-webbrowser-content/11251567

Answer (score 0):

You can get all buttons like this

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
```

It might be easier to submit the form instead.

```
Dim form As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("formId")

If form IsNot Nothing Then
        form.InvokeMember("submit")
End If
```

Comment: Ah'. I have yet to try it but the problem is that I don't know if "Submit" is the ID. I tried and I had an error. Now would you be able to check and see what the ID really is for the Sign In button for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub ClickSearching(ByVal targetType As String, ByVal targetText As String)
    Dim bFounded As Boolean = False
    Dim tags As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName(targetType)

    For Each elem As HtmlElement In tags
        Application.DoEvents()

        If elem.GetAttribute("value") = targetText Then
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
            bFounded = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not bFounded Then
        Throw New Exception("No se encontró ningún resultado para la función ClickSearching(" & targetType & "," & targetText & ")")
    End If
End Sub
```